# How manage two independent windows in OpenGL?

Tags: windows, opengl, glut

I have 2 reshape functions and 2 display function. Each to show something that is completely independent to the other, but they must show what they are meant to show together (two independent things showing at the same time); each on it's own window.
How can I manage those 2 windows? Can anyone explain or indicate some site that explain it (I couldn't find any)? I need something really simple, if possible.
Thanks and sory for the bad English.

Comment: Did you actually ***try*** this already and run into a specific issue that we could help you with? You mention "showing at the same time" and I can see potential issues with this if you use VSYNC, you may wind up drawing windows at 1/2 your refresh rate if you try to drive both windows using a single thread. GLUT's probably not the best framework for this sort of thing, it has a really inflexible main/event loop design.

Comment: You need to think about your software architecture. Most likeley you would have two independant list of renderable entities, one belonging to the first context that is bound to window A, and one that belongs to a second context that is bound to window B. Then just make either context active and draw the approriate list?

Comment: There is already a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465462/multiple-windows-opengl-glut?rq=1), though it has no accepted answer. The general idea though, is that GLUT callbacks are per-window. My disdain for GLUT comes from the fact that the main loop that drives ***all*** of the windows event management runs in a single thread and it is not designed to allow you to process the events for each window using separate loops.

Answer (score 2):

I take it, that you're referring to the use of GLUT. First things first: *GLUT is not part of OpenGL!* (I stopped counting how many times I had to write this into an answer). GLUT operates on the premise, that you register callbacks for each window; each window also has its own OpenGL context.

For a practical use of this you might want to look at my *frustum* codesample, which uses multiple GLUT windows to render the "same" scene from different angles: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum/frustum.c